# GMSPlace object from Lantitude and Longitide

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I get Latitude and longitude from API from which I want the photos, address, rating etc of the places.

I think the details of a place can be got only from GMSPlace object but am not able to figure out as in how to get the place object from Latitude and Longitude.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Probably, but it would help us a lot if you could show us the code you have so far in your attempts to figure it out, and we can start from there.

Comment: @LouisLeung thnxs for ur response. I got this working by calling the places nearby api with latitude and longitude details, by specifying the radius as 10.